# Power BI - exclude the duration of overlapping events within a specific period

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a table in powerbi with the list of problems that cause downtime in specific machines. The structure of the table is as follows:

| machine_id | start_timestamp | downtime (sec.) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10/10/2021 7:03:00 AM | 100 |
| 1 | 10/10/2021 7:04:00 AM | 30 |
| 1 | 10/10/2021 7:06:00 AM | 300 |
| 2 | 10/10/2021 7:08:00 AM | 20 |

- **machine_id** is the id of the machine affected by the problem in that row
- **start_timestamp** is Date/time that tells when the problem started
- **downtime (sec.)** is the total time in seconds that machine was down due to the problem in that row

What I want to calculate as a 'measure' is, for each specific machine and for a certain period of time, the total downtime without overlapping values. That means, if there is already a problem that caused a downtime in a certain time, the existence of a new problem that overlaps that one shouldn't be added in the calculation (or eventually added partially).

As an example, for machine_id = 1, **between 10/10/2021 7:00:00AM and 10/10/2021 7:10:00AM** I would obtain a total downtime of 100 + 240 = 340 seconds.

Can you please help me? I have tried many approaches without success. If I need to clarify anything else just say.

Thanks!

Comment: In example where do you get 240sec?

Comment: @Siva It's from the last time increment.  Since he only wants up to 7:10 AM, he would only be counting 240 seconds of the the 300 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one way with a previous PowerQuery step.

1. Create a column in PowerQuery using the List.DateTimes function. Inputs are start_timestamp, downtime,
   = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Date", "Custom", each List.DateTimes([start_timestamp],[#"downtime (sec.)"],#duration(0,0,0,1)))
2. Expand the column. This will create one register for each downtime second.
3. Create a new column concatenating machine_id and the newly created column with the downtime seconds. Format this as text, I called it Time_and_Machine:

[image]

Now you should have a table which has one row for each second of each issue with your machines. There will be duplicates in Time_and_Machine, you remove duplicates in powerquery and end up with one row for each second and each machine with issues.

Now you can go back to PowerBI and create a measure which simply Counts the rows:
SecondsDown = Count(Down[machine_id]):

[image]

[image]